# One-liner conditional operation

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have the following conditional structure multiple times within the cases of a switch statement. (see arrow)

```
  switch (field.target.name) {
    case "email":
      if (!isEmail(field.target.value)) {  <-----------
        dispatch('has_error', field)       <-----------
      }                                    <-----------
      return                               <-----------
    case "phoneNumber":
    case "companyPhoneNumber":
      if (!isMobilePhone(field.target.value, 'en-CA')) {
        dispatch('has_error', field)
      }
      return
  }
```

I'd like to shorten it so it doesn't take up 4 lines. I can do something like

```
!isEmail(field.target.value) ? dispatch('has_error', field) : null
return
```

But that seems awkward.

Any elegant solutions out there?

Comment: `nil` isn't actually a thing in JavaScript

Comment: @Paul fixed sir

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is better for this sort of question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current code is readable and fine. You could write it as

```
return !isEmail(field.target.value) && dispatch('has_error', field);
```

or

```
return isEmail(field.target.value) || dispatch('has_error', field);
```

This combines two "techniques":

1. Using `return` on the same line as some statement, in order to both execute that statement and then immediately return from the function. However, this can be confusing--a reader of your code may think that the return value is somehow important. And it works only if the function is not normally expected to return anything.
2. Writing `if (a) b` as `a && b` (or `if (!a) b` as `a || b`). But this approach to writing the equivalent of an `if` statement is generally frowned on as being too terse--it hides the essential `if` nature of the logic. Also, if used in stand-alone fashion, as in `a && b;`, many linters will (rightfully) complain about a stand-alone expression.

Comment: awesome answer thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's valid to do something like this:

```
if (!isEmail(field.target.value)) return dispatch('has_error', field);
```

But some folks don't care for how long that winds up being.

Comment: This doesn't do the same thing. The original code returns whether or not the condition is true.

Comment: No it doesn't, look again.  I left off the case statement, but every return was just `return` with no value.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below, if`isEmail(field.target.value)`return `false`, `dispatch('has_error', field)` will be executed.

```
isEmail(field.target.value) || dispatch('has_error', field);
return;
```